# *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM Name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

When i call below method `_productName.text = _productInfo.Name`
the code stop here and throw the error by breakpoint debug.

Please guide me....

Thanks! Here is my code:

```
-(void)setProductInfo:(OnGoProducts*)prduct
{

    _productInfo = prduct;
    _productName.text = _productInfo.Name;
    NSDictionary* dict = [_productInfo.json objectFromJSONString];
    _productPrice.text = [dict objectForKey:@"MRP"];

    if([self.productInfo.type isEqualToString:@"Deals"])
    {
        [self.shownProperties addObject:@"Discount Value"];
        [self.shownProperties addObject:@"Discount Type"];
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray* allkeys = [dict allKeys];

        NSMutableSet* set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:allkeys];

        NSArray* excludedKeys = @[@"ItemCode", @"id", @"Name", @"createdById", @"jobTypeId", @"createdByFullName", @"publicURL", @"ExpiredOn", @"Quantity", @"In_Stock", @"hrsOfOperation", @"createdOn",
                                  @"Image_Name", @"Image_URL", @"Latitude", @"Longitude", @"Attachments", @"Additional_Details", @"jobComments", @"Current_Job_Status,Category_Mall", @"MRP", @"Insights",
                                  @"Current_Job_StatusId", @"Next_Seq_Nos", @"CreatedSubJobs", @"Next_Job_Statuses", @"offersCount", @"productsCount", @"businessType", @"storeId", @"CategoryType", @"SubCategoryType", @"P3rdCategory", @"Category_Mall", @"PackageName",@"Current_Job_Status", @"jobTypeName",@"Units", @"guestUserId", @"guestUserEmail", @"Image"];

        NSSet* set1 = [NSSet setWithArray:excludedKeys];

        [set minusSet:set1];

        self.shownProperties = [set allObjects];
    }

    NSMutableArray* excludedKeys = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int index = 0; index < self.shownProperties.count; ++index)
    {
        NSString* value = [dict objectForKey:[self.shownProperties objectAtIndex:index]];
        if(!value || ![value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            [excludedKeys addObject:[self.shownProperties objectAtIndex:index]];
        }
        if([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            value = [value stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
            if(value.length <= 0)
            {
                [excludedKeys addObject:[self.shownProperties objectAtIndex:index]];
            }
        }

    }

    NSSet* set1 = [NSSet setWithArray:excludedKeys];
    NSMutableSet* set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:self.shownProperties];
    [set minusSet:set1];

    self.shownProperties = [set allObjects];

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 50, 0);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Does your `OnGoProducts` class have a `Name` property?

Comment: try this   
_productName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_productInfo.Name];

Comment: Srija first you have to check whether you have name at your dictionary.Before that show me your response which you get.

Comment: _productName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_productInfo.Name]; is not working

Answer (score -1):

i think exception is due to the reason that the object _productInfo is NSDictionary type. please debug the code and check whether _productInfo is NSdictionary type or OnGoProducts type.

Comment: it is ONGOProducts type.

Answer (score -1):

First of all please explain your objects which are you used in your code like productInfo?. 
If productInfo is a dictionary then you can get the name like `_productInfo[@"Name"];`. If its not then first tell me what are these objects. Thanks.Hope this help.

Comment: These are ONGOProducts type

Comment: In _productInfo, it showing the details of products

Comment: Printing description of self->_productInfo:
{
    "CREATED_BY_ID" = 3118;
    DESCRIPTION = "PEZlYXR1cmVQcm9kdWN0c0pvYnM6IDB4N2ZmNDRiOWRhNzkwPg==";
    ID = 113729;
    "ITEM_CODE" = "acf63d2e-2533-40b1-9f4c-b5aaf02383e3";
    "Image_URL" = "http://storeongo.com:8085/coin/files/vusar/jobs/xlsupload/attachments/3118_14556003870271.jpg";
    JOBTYPENAME = "Exterior Paint Protection";
    JSON = "";
    NAME = "EXTERIOR Gold treatment";
    "PARENT_ID" = 113745;
    jobId = 56646;
}

Comment: _productInfo is a type in that name is a string , i try this line_productInfo[@" NAME"]; but it is showing like this "Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type ONGOProducts".

Comment: look in above code you use  _productName.text = _productInfo.Name; but here it may be like this  _productName.text = _productInfo. NAME;. Try this may be this help.

Comment: In _productInfo name(Name) is a property string we can't write as a NAME